# Redeclaring function parameters as variables?

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I can't seem to find an answer for this anywhere on the 'Net...

Is there any reason, advantage, or disadvantage to redeclaring function parameters as local variables?

Example:

```
function(param1, param2) {
  var param1, param2;
  ...etc...
}
```

Seems extremely redundant to me, but maybe I'm missing something...?

Thanks,

Brian

Comment: is it Javascript? By the way, nice nickname.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the names of the declared variables are the same as the ones as the function parameters then it does absolutely nothing. **Completely worthless**. Doesn't even change the value of the variable.

Comment: This is what I thought as well.  I'm cleaning up someone else's code, and I couldn't think of any reason why this would be at all necessary or even useful.  You pretty much confirmed my suspicions, thank you.

Comment: @trinithis - Do you know if this answer is true for all the major browsers?

Comment: I would assume so. I would find it hard to believe that even a crappy browser would get this wrong.

Comment: The only thing it accomplishes is enforcing locally-scoped variables. In case you end up renaming the function arguments and forgetting to change the assignments - they would end up as a global variable, but I can't see a situation where preventing a bug when creating a bug is of any use....

Comment: @bryc That doesn't help. The renaming problem just gets pushed down the ladder.

Answer (score 2):

There is no good reason to ever redeclare a local variable with the same name as a parameter.  Most languages wouldn't allow this, but JavaScript allows pretty much everything.

Answer (score 2):

It will be useful, when user didn't pass any thing on function calls.

for example

```
function X(param1, param2){
   param1 = param1 || 1; //set default values if param1 is nothing
   param2 = param2 || {};
}
```

but in your example, you have overwritten function's parameters, so it will be just like

```
function X(){
  var param1, param2;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, but my example wouldn't need var keyword, because they are delared in function arguments.

Comment: Also one would have issues passing in values to the function!

Answer (score 0):

Often this is unnecessary, but it can be useful in some cases.

A couple of examples:

If you modify the values of those variables in the function, but need to know what the original value was later in the function, you'll do well to have made a copy up front.

Sometimes it is convenient to have a very descriptive name in the declaration, like `first_integer_in_product_list`, but would rather work with just `i` when writing code inside the function.

Comment: The OP asked about redeclaring the variable, not reassigning a new value to it.

Comment: Yeah, they're not making copies or assigning handy variable names, they're just using `var` to redeclare, with no values.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't hurt anything, and unless you need to do something off the wall like the answer from S. Mark it should be avoided. It can lead to less readable code, and if you're not paying attention to variable scopes or if you lose track of names it can make for a spaghetti warehouse.

Answer (score 0):

You should mention in the post which language you are talking about, in most that would be an error if they had the same name. I assume the most likely reason for being able to do so in some language would be to alter its scope, like make its duration static rather than destroying immediately as the function completes.

Comment: I apologize, it is indeed JavaScript in this particular case.

Using `var` as in my example doesn't change the scope, AFAIK.  The variables aren't even used anywhere, nor are they copied to any others.  I'm seeing this quite a bit in the code, so I was beginning to wonder if this was some sort of unwritten 'trick'... ;)